# Why are all possible integers "true" in the range of long int inside if-statement in C++, but 0 is not?

Tags: c++, if-statement, int, implicit-conversion, boolean-logic

Basically, how does an if-statement analize whether an integer is true or false? These two simple lines print out "Hello", with a positive integer 764:

```
int a=764;
if(a){ cout<<"Hello"; }else{ cout<<"Bye"; } //Hello
```

If i change the integer from positive to negative (-231) it prints out "Hello" as well:

```
int a=-231;
if(a){ cout<<"Hello"; }else{ cout<<"Bye"; } //Hello
```

But if i set `a` to be `0`, it gets `false`

```
int a=0;
if(a){ cout<<"Hello"; }else{ cout<<"Bye"; } //Bye
```

It goes `true` with the range of a `long int`, from `-2147483647` to `2147483647` with only one exception: `0`.
How does that happen? And what is that `if` actually doing to determine so?

Comment: To looks like the conversion from int to Boolean happens based on the value of integer. If it is 0 it is returns false and for anything other than 0 it returns true.

Comment: You can check it out here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior by design. An `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }` statement in C/C++ evaluates a boolean expression that will ultimately be either `true` (the `if` block executes) or `false` (the `else` block executes). When you pass an integer as a condition, it must necessarily be reduced to either true or false, and the compiler actually interprets this as `if (integer != 0)`. This will be the same for whatever integer type, signed or unsigned.

This is a very common idiom in C/C++, although one may argue that it is not the most legible of notations, and you should always make it explicit that you intend to verify whether the integer is 0 or not by using `if (integer != 0)`.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the edit! ;)